# How to pass WSL filenames to C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm struggling with a piece of C# program that takes a filename as input argument.
Here's a minimal sample code:

```
namespace Ns
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0) return;
            string filename = args[0];
            Console.Write("Bytes received: ");
            foreach (var c in filename)
                Console.Write("{0:X2}", (int)c);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("File {0} {1}found", filename, File.Exists(filename) ? "" : "not ");
        }
    }
}
```

I do have a file named `a*b`.

On Windows's cmd.exe, using tab to complete the name, I send `Program.exe ab`.
The program outputs:

> Bytes received: 61F02A62
> File a?b found

From a WSL terminal, the filename gets escaped and the call becomes: `./Program.exe a\*b`
The program outputs:

> Bytes received: 612A62
> File a*b not found

But if I call `./Program.exe ab`, C# finds the file.

I then copy that Program.exe to a real Linux machine, create another a*b file, then call `./Program.exe a\*b`
The program outputs:

> Bytes received: 612A62
> File a*b found

And of course, Linux doesn't understand `ab`.

The asterisk is \u002A, so just 1 byte in UTF-8. On Linux, sending an asterisk works fine. On Windows, it has to be replaced with \uF02A.

This program receives filenames from scripts on Windows, WSL, and Linux (usually from find -exec). How do I handle the input so that it works regardless?

Of course, I can detect a 0x2A character and replace it with 0xF02A on the fly (for WSL), but there are other touchy characters like asterisk, and I don't know all of them. Plus there are probably some valid UTF-8 codes that contain 0x2A, so I guess I can't blindly replace every occurrences.

[EDIT]
I ended up making a substitution list for those weird characters (listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721147/invalid-characters-in-a-filename-on-windows)). Now both WSL and native Windows are happy. Linux fails but I can just disable the substitution if Linux is detected.

```
    internal class Program
{
    static List<char> bad  = new List<char>(new char[] {'<', '>', ':', '"', '\\', '|', '?', '*' });
    static char[]     good = { '\uF03C', '\uF03E', '\uF03A', '\uF022', '\uF05C', '\uF07C', '\uF03F', '\uF02A' };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0) return;

        string filename = "";
        foreach (char c in args[0])
        {
            int idx = bad.IndexOf(c);
            filename += idx == -1 ? c : good[idx];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File {0} {1}found", filename, File.Exists(filename) ? "" : "not ");
    }
}
```

Comment: So the file contains `0xF02A` and not `0x2A`?

Comment: @CodeCaster The content of the file is irrelevant as it is never opened here. The problem is with the filename. It contains an asterisk and is stored on NTFS (no idea how NTFS encodes it). If I pass this filename from WSL to C# (on Windows) as a utf-8 string, C# fails (it works on Linux). WSL mixes both Windows and Linux, making things worse. The WSL terminal sends 3 utf-8 bytes (612A62) but C# expects 4 bytes (61F02A62).

Comment: @MeganRain What release of WSL are you on (and Windows)?  Just want to be sure I'm testing the same.  I'm currently at 1.0.0 (WSL installed from the Store), but I can test on another system as well.  I'm trying to reproduce using "standard" commands rather than your app at the moment.  For instance, `powershell.exe -c getchild-item a\*b` from inside WSL is working for me, regardless of whether the file is on ext4 or NTFS (9P).  Not quite sure it's a valid "comparison" to your use-case, but I always like to see if I can root-cause the issue separately from the code if possible.

Comment: I of course meant the file name, but I'm questioning what its actual name is. Can you show a repro, including how you create the file?

Comment: Sorry, files are created either natively on Linux or through WSL on Windows. The test file I used here was created from WSL with touch 'a*b'

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm using WSL 1 on Windows 10 LTSC (21H2 19044.2130), debian distro.

Comment: @MeganRain Ok, my test-case for this is still working for me under WSL1 Debian.  What happens for you if you `powershell.exe -c getchild-item a\*b`?  Does it return the file correctly or still give you an error?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds From WSL, `powershell.exe -c Get-ChildItem a\*b` returns a list of all files starting with an 'a' (case insensitive). Inside powershell, `Get-ChildItem a\*b` fails, saying no such file exists.

Comment: @MeganRain Even more odd -- For me `touch a abc a\*b; powershell.exe -c Get-ChildItem a\*b` only returns the `ab` file.  (WSL1 on Windows 10 with `conhost.exe` as the terminal).

Comment: I think the main issue is that Linux and WSL are able to create valid NTFS paths and filenames that Windows does not support. For example, I can create a directory on NTFS that ends with 3 dots using `mkdir mydir...` and I can access it from WSL, but Windows refuses to enter that directory (both explorer and cmd). When I use `echo hello >'a*b'`, bash lists it as `a*b`, Windows displays it as ab (the weird character looks like a multiplication dot) but I can still open this file from explorer. C#'s `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` and `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` do not list '*' as invalid

Comment: I ended up making a list of "bad" characters with a substitution list. Now the program works on Windows (both WSL and native) but fails on Linux, so I just have to detect either the platform. I'll try to edit the question to add the new code.

Comment: `*` (U+002A,  *Asterisk*) is a reserved character and [can't be used in names for files and directories, regardless of the file system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions). On the other hand,  `` (U+F02A,  *Private Use*) is a [valid Unicode character](https://codepoints.net/U+F02A?lang=en)…

Comment: In Windows command prompt: `echo hello>"a*b"` leads to error message 
*The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.*